# Sending datetime from AWS ec2 instance to Gmail with moment js

Tags: javascript, amazon-ec2, momentjs

I supposed to get `time` from current `datetime` of `new Date()` in `javascript` using `moment js` and convert it to `local time`.

```
var time = moment.utc(new Date()).local().format('HH:mm');
console.log(time);
```

And send the `time` to `gmail`.

If I send it from my local server, the time display in the email as what i want. But if i send the time from remote server(aws instance), it display the utc time in gmail.

Sample:

```
new Date() = 2018-04-24T08:20:54.622Z

time in email from localserver = 16:20 (+8 in my country), correct for me.

time in email from aws ec2 instance = 08:20, I don't want it.
```

Anyone have an idea about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Node? If so AWS servers are set so their local time is UTC. These should be the same on AWS and different on your local:

```
var utctime = moment.utc().format('HH:mm');
console.log(utctime);
var localtime = moment.utc().local().format('HH:mm');
console.log(localtime);
```

If this is running in your browser and you are getting different behavior pointed at your local server and the AWS server, then something very weird is going on because your machine and the browser should be used for the local time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can solve this issue using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/). You can hard code your local time-zone so that it will always convert date into that specific timezone.

Example:

```
moment(date).tz('Asia/Tokyo').format(format)
```

Instead of `Asia/Tokyo` put your local time zone.

If you don't know your local time zone, use `guess()` API of moment-timezone library:

```
var zoneName = moment.tz.guess(); // just to get your local time zone name. Don't keep it in code otherwise it will pick local time zone of AWS instance
```

Below is working code snippet:

```js
var zoneName = moment.tz.guess();
console.log(zoneName);

var time = moment('2018-04-24T08:20:54.622Z').tz(zoneName).format('HH:mm');
console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.11/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: @noyruto88, did you check my answer?